# Setting font for QTextEdit is ignored for no apparent reason

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to set font of `QTextEdit` to be the same as of `QTreeWidget`.

When I get the font from `QTextEdit` and try to set it to `QTreeWidget`, it does not work. However, if I create a new font `QFont("Segoe UI", 9)`, which happens to be the same as `QTreeWidget` has on my platform (Windows 7) and set it to `QTextEdit`, it works.

The following code prints `True` for the font comparison, but does not work as expected. Uncommenting the `self.text.setFont(new_font)` fixes it. Why?

```
import string
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


TEXT = string.printable[:-5]

def print_font(font):
    print("Family: {}, Size: {}".format(font.family(), font.pointSize()))


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.list = QTreeWidget(self) 
        self.list.addTopLevelItem(QTreeWidgetItem((TEXT,)))
        self.list.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.list.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.list.setMinimumHeight(25)

        self.text = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text.setText(TEXT)
        self.text.setMinimumHeight(25)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.list)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)

        self.resize(620, 20)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

        list_font = self.list.font()
        new_font = QFont("Segoe UI", 9)
        print(list_font == new_font)
        self.text.setFont(list_font)
#         self.text.setFont(new_font)

        print_font(self.list.font())
        print_font(self.text.font())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't safely assume that the properties reported by QFont are the same as those that are actually used. They may be, but it's not guaranteed.

To safely get the actual values used, you need to use [QFontInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontinfo.html). On Linux, I get different values from QFont and QFontInfo, but the font transfer succeeds; on Windows, they're the same, but the transfer fails. Huh.

Anyway, there seems to be some issue with copying fonts on Windows, but I'm unable to diagnose exactly what it might be. Something to do with the font-cache, maybe?

I thought that:

```
    list_font = QFont(self.list.font())
```

might make a difference - but it doesn't. In the end, the only thing that worked for me on Windows was this:

```
    list_font = QFont()
    list_font.fromString(self.list.font().toString())
    self.text.setFont(list_font)
```

Comment: Good insight. Thanks.